# Integers of the form $a^2-b^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, integers

I would like to know if there is a formula to calculate the cardinality of the set of all the numbers of the form $a^2-b^2$ such that $a^2-b^2\leq n$ and $b\leq a$.

Numerically I found something around $3n/4$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $a^2-b^2\equiv 0,1,3\pmod4$, and every number $r\equiv 0,1,3\pmod4$ has a representation of the above form. For the proof observe following two identities
$$
(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1,(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2=4k
$$

Answer (score 3):

Every odd number is the difference of two squares. Namely,
$$2k+1=(k+1)^2-k^2$$

Every multiple of $4$ is also the difference if two squares:
$$4k=(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2$$

But an even number that is not multiple of $4$ is not the difference os any two squares, since
$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$
and both factors have the same parity.

So an integer number is the difference of two squares iff is not congruent to $2$ mod $4$.

Answer (score 1):

it is everything of form $4k,4k+1$ and $4k+3$ so the cardinality is floor(${3n\over4}+{5\over4}$).

everything of $4k$ is reachable by $a=k+1,b=k-1$ and if $k=0,a=b$.

everything of $4k+1$ is reachable by $a=2k+1, b=2k$.

everything of $4k+3$ by $a=2k+2,b=2k+1$.